# plotting normal distribution

Tags: differential-equations

I've been really struggling with Mathematica so far, so I need some help to try to figure out how to approach this problem.
[image]

I'm assuming I would have to have to find an values for each case, so it would also help a lot if someone could explain how to set a domain in this program.

Comment: What does part 1) say?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MMA SE! To plot a function $f(x)$ over some range $a < x < b$, one can use

```
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

So, the domain is not inherently associated with the function itself, but only with the plotting procedure.

This way of "setting the domain" is a very generic pattern in mathematica; for example, a list with `i` ranging from `a` to `b` (albeit in discrete steps) is `Table[f[i], {i, a, b}]`, and $\sum_{n=a}^b a_n$ is `Sum[a[n], {n, a, b}]`, etc.

So, in this case, you could define the function `u` as

```
u[x_] := Sum[a[n]*Sin[n*Pi*x/24], {n, 1, 25}]
```

and then evaluate

```
Plot[u[x], {x, 0, 24}]
```

as long as you have some working definition for `a[n]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Will it work if a[n] is in equation form instead of a constant?

Comment: By that, do you mean something like `a[n_] := <expression>` or an explicit value like `n^2`? If so, in either case, yes!